# A strange message in a library

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, story, knowledge

A few days ago I entered a small and ancient library in China Town, and while I was looking for some interesting book to borrow, a torn slip of paper fell from a shelf.

On it, a strange message… some kind of poem I could not give a sense to…

On a side, someone wrote a series of number with a pencil, no idea what could they mean…

Here you can see what I'm talking about:

[image]

**I'm pretty confident that a secret message is hidden behind these lines… could you help me to find it?**

---

*(Here is the plain text version of the message, if you need it)*

```
Fellowship with men following the receptive earth
The family had some difficulty at the beginning
But the abysmal army made it progress
Receptive earth, oppression of inner truth: revolution!
The taming power of the small, 
The taming power of the great!
Grace of the clinging fire, 
Approach and break through the clan!
```

Hint 1:

> You'll need some knowledge (or some googling...) to solve the first level of the puzzle

Hint 2:

> Take a closer look to the picture to get a hint on how to solve the puzzle

Hint 3:

> The message ends with an exclamation point (!) and contains a comma (,)...

Comment: Are the numbers relevant?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are: they must have been written by someone who tried to decipher the message before us...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A <s>Very Partial</s> *Not as Partial as before* answer to get somebody else started, since nobody has attempted this, and I won't have the time in the next couple of days: The poem is composed of

> names for [I Ching hexagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hexagrams_of_the_I_Ching), which have a numerical value.

Continuing several days later..

With the hint in place, it seems likely that the values I mentioned above are irrelevant, as already deduced by M Oehm. So it's down to finding the correct way to interpret the symbols themselves.

Collecting everything on one line we get the following (in unicode. if you have display issues, M Oehm's answer has ascii art)

> ䷌䷐䷁ / ䷤䷂/ ䷜䷃䷢ / ䷁䷅䷻䷰ / ䷈ / ䷙ / ䷕䷝ / ䷒䷪䷤

Then using the scribbled number sequence 4,3,3,3,2,1 as a guide,

> taking the numbers to mean the length of the morse symbol, and reading the hexagrams from bottom to the top, (broken line is short, whole line is long), we get
>  `-.-- --- ..- -.. .. . .. / -. -. --- ...- . / .-..-. .-...- ...-.- / ...... .-.--- --..-. -.---./ ---.-- / ---..- / -.-..- -.--.- / --.... -----. -.-.--`
>  `Y    O   U    D  I  E (I   N  N  O   V    E etc)`

Since it's surprisingly tricky to decode without additional numbers, I'll just leave it at interpreting the handwritten number sequence as being the whole message, which would then read, ominously enough,

> YOU DIE...

I'll try decoding the rest of the poem later.

> Looks like the previous person trying to solve this got the message wrong, it doesn't read "YOU DIE", instead the beginning is very likely "YOU DISCOVERED"

After that, though, I'm getting nowhere, and writing a small piece of code to try every word in a dictionary to see if it fits would take a bit of time, (which I don't really have), so please feel free to continue from here.

—

The third hint seems to make it painfully obvious that there is at least one typo in the problem. M Oehm discovered a very plausible solution that assumes there are actually two.

As it stands, the message is

> You discover a fin in the fog. TY you can go home.

---

**OP EDIT**: I'm really sorry for the many mistakes this puzzle did contain, and which I hope I've finally fixed. The puzzle has now been modified to give the intended solution, that is:

> "You discovered the I Ching, now you can go home!"

Something has gone wrong in the creation of this puzzle, that I think has a good idea behind it, but a dramatically problematic execution (just after a long revision I found that the table I used to convert symbols into code was uncorrect).

I'll take all the blame for this, hoping it will help me in the future to create better and less faulty puzzles; and I take the occasion to apologize with all the guys who tried (and managed, despite the errors!) to solve the puzzle, and who lost a lot of precious time just because of my superficiality.

Comment: You're on the right track

Comment: O.P. EDIT: I've modified the originally posted picture to help solving the second part of the puzzle

Comment: My fault... The note on the paper should have been "4,3,3,3,2,3...". I hope there are no more errors in my puzzle (I swear I've re-checked it a lot of times... :( )

Comment: I've uptaded the picture with the correct version of the note.

Comment: I like the idea that the original solver misdecoded as "You die" -- and died. The Morse I Ching self-fulfilling prophecy. The problem with writing a small program is that it comes up with a huge amount of possibilities. It might be more promising to run a dictionary of longish morse-encoded words on the message for candidates. "Discovered" is apparently the longest possible word. None of the others stick out as typical of a quotation or answer.

Comment: (The whole message could end with "key" or "try", though.)

Comment: I thought it would have been easier for "Puzzling guys" converting a long sequence of dots and dashes from Morse Code to text.. that's why I gave just a small hint to start the conversion job... I'm afraid this process is much more difficult than I expected...

Comment: @MOehm, starting from the end could be even more difficult, considering that the last character of the sentence is NOT a letter...

Comment: I really like M Oehm’s backstory idea :-) I’ll try to whip up the dictionary search once the kids have gone to bed; that’ll be in a couple of hours, hopefully.

Comment: Code promptly up-whipped, but manual runs only give red herrings for the next couple of words. Or to be more accurate, "nine alive otter"s and "dreariest woe"s. The problem is that for any combination of dits and dahs, many different words will always match, and there will be several possible continuations, so ruling out even a single possibility requires an exponential amount of effort. Searching for likely words like "secret", "message", "hidden" or "the" also yielded nothing very useful.

Comment: I've got as far as 4,3,3,3,2,3,4,3,4,1,3... No idea if this will help.

Comment: Hunter's comment makes me think that the last character in the message is an exclamation mark. [Here](https://pastebin.com/6VpH1jQF) is what a search with the 20-percentile words from Scowl yields after removing the trailing `-.-.--`. Nothing really stands out to me. There's a possible THE or another YOU/R in the middle. The problem is that using a bigger dictionary only produces more noise.

Comment: @MOehm your suppositions are right... "!" & "THE" & "YOU" are there...

Comment: @Xenocacia, yeah, the text in the last spoiler tag has that, and follows with "1,3". Now, if there really are the words "the" and another "you" in the middle as OP seems to say, then there are exactly two dots between them. (Those would be the last dot of "receptive earth" and the first dot of "conflict".) I have a very hard time coming up with a sentence that has "the I you" or "the ee you" in it. So that would mean the "the" would have to be at the only other place with "-.....", but that would conflict with the scribbled numbers. OP, care to comment?

Comment: Thanks. That breaks up the message into digestable chunks. I guess it is "You discovered ... the item of (?). Now you can go home." I'm quite sure about the last part.

Comment: Oops, there's a third place for "you". Sorry :-). I only got "It can go home", but @MOehm is clearly correct.

Comment: The code before "now" could well be another piece of punctuation, but the ony one that fits is a slash, which doesn't make a lot of sense -- I expected a full stop or semicolon.

Comment: That's what I thought too. "You discover a fin in the pot / now you can go home!" makes for complete sentences, but doesn't make much sense otherwise.

Comment: (Oops again, that's not a p, so it's not "pot".)

Comment: "You discover a fin in the fog. TY you can go home!" ("a fin in the fog" is a book by Mary Geiger, apparently. No, I don't believe this is correct, either. :-)

Comment: @Bass: you're finding a lot of funny alternatives to the intended solution! You deserve some extra-point for this! :)

Comment: @MOehm: you have had another good supposition, another punctuation is there... hey, everybody... you're really close to the solution, come on! :)

Comment: @hunter, I think i'll have to give up. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but the only sane-ish sentence I can form has the word "exir" in it instead of exit. Can you think of any additional hints? Seems like we are completely stuck here.

Comment: @Bass: M Oehm has deciphered 90% of the message "You discovered .... now you can go home!" is correct, you're missing exactly 2 (or 3...) words and a punctuation mark, it can't be so difficult now! PS: think about it: what have you discovered thanks to this puzzle?

Comment: I suspect that the answer is "You have discovered the I Ching, you can go home now!", buf if so, there are two misencodings.The remaining portion is `-...-...-.-.......-.-----..-.`, but it should be `-...o...-.-.......-.--.--..-=`. (The `=` is a dash misencoded as dot and the `o` a dot misencoded as dash.) The problem here is the the encoding for THE is part of the encoding for ICHING, and there is a typo in the _real_ THE -- I always worked from the wrong THE! If that's true, the Youthful Folly should be the Army and Limitation should be the Inner Truth.

Comment: I don’t think that can be possible, since OP specifically told us he had rechecked the puzzle several times. OP, please tell me we didn’t spend hours upon hours on an unsolvable problem that you could at any point have checked and fixed in 5 minutes or less. Please?

Comment: Well, it's easy to make a mistake here, because there's not only the Morse code, but also the correspondence with the hexagrams to take care of. In March, there was [another More puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49814/encoding-morse-code) that had two typos in it. Now we must rewrite our programs to include "fuzzy" matches, so that a mis-morsed THE is considered alongside the correct DEN. `:)`

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what is the shortest word that can *not* be found in that string if we allow one dit-dah reversal.. (off to code a bit..)

Comment: Apparently, that would be "pig". [Here](https://pastebin.com/YHGpZmgx) are some stats and some of the longest words that can be found in the string if we allow for one typo.

Comment: Somewhat interestingly, even allowing for two mistakes, there are still 5 three-letter words that cannot possibly be found in the morse string here. Unsurprisingly, they all are mostly comprised of the longest morse letters. They are "foy", "gyp", "lop", "pya" and "pyr". Now that those words are decidedly ruled out, the puzzle should become that much easier to solve. :-) ~

Comment: Guys, in this moment I can't re-recheck the puzzle, I'm doing it tomorrow as soon as possible. The intended is "... The I Ching...", I can't imagine what could have been wrong in the creation of the puzzle (I used Excel to create it and to avoid "manual" errors). It appears Excel betrayed me at least a couple of times... 

Comment: Ps: the first mistake in this puzzle was due to the fact that Excel converted the string "..." (three dots) into a single symbol made up of 3 dots. Obviously without asking my permission to do it...  I'm wondering if the cause of the second "double mistake" is due to something like that

Comment: Does someone already pointed out that there are leters in gray in the text, soMe - prOgress - eaRth - Small - gracE, forming the word MORSE ?

Comment: Yes, Excel does some surprising edits on its own if it isn't explicitly told not to. I liked the puzzle. I think puzzles on PSE can be experimental, so it's no shame that the Morse decoding didn't quite work. Such things happen. We've learned that unspaced Morse is hard to crack, unless the message is carefully composed  and short, perhaps. It's unfortunate that one tends to throw a computer program at it, which doesn't fit the story, where the protagonist is supposed to solve the code with pen and paper.

Comment: I do like the possibility of ambiguous decoding, though. Perhaps the scribbled numbers and the seganographic hint towards Morse could have been replaced by the wrong YOU DIE. The solver must then find out that Mrse was used _and_ that the original solver was on the wrong track. Perhaps a bit too devious. If nothing else, the I Ching reference in this puzzle has made me read _The Man in the High Castle_ again.

Answer (score 5):

Building on [Bass's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56854/42302)

> I looked up the numeric values of the hexagrams in the text.
>
> ```
>  13 - Fellowship with men 
>  17 - following 
>  2  - the Receptive Earth
>
>  
>  37 - The family
>  had
>  3  - some difficulty at the beginning
>
>  
>  But
>  29 - the abysmal
>  4  - youthful folly 
>  made it
>  35 - progress
>
>  
>  2  - Receptive Earth,
>  6  - conflict
>  your 
>  60 - limitation: 
>  49 - revolution!
>  
>  9  - The Taming Power of the Small,
>  
>  26 - The Taming Power of the Great!
>  
>  22 - Grace
>  of
>  30 - the clinging fire,
>  
>  19 - approach
>  and
>  43 - break through
>  37 - the Clan!
> ```
>
> or just the numbers: 13-17-2, 37-3, 29-4-35, 2-6-60-49, 9, 26, 22-30, 19-43-37
>  I tried converting this from decimal to ASCII, but it came back a gibberish.

@Xenocacia pointed out

> There are faded letters in the note which spells out "morse".

Hopefully someone else will have some ideas of what to try next, or at the least I will have saved someone a little effort looking things up.

Comment: Some of the hexagrams (namely Receptive Earth and Taming Power) are capitalized differently, perhaps that means something?

Comment: Also, if we were to take the two lines separated by comma as one sentence, we end up with 6 sentences - one for each of the scribbled numbers. I haven't been able to figure out what they mean though..

Comment: @Barker: you solved the first level of the puzzle, now you have to understand how to use the information you found.

Comment: @VotBear: capitalization and structure of the sentences are irrelevant to solve the puzzle

Comment: O.P. EDIT: I've modified the originally posted picture to help solving the second part of the puzzle

Comment: @Hunter Does that mean that line structure is also irrelevant (e.g. what text is all on the same line as each other)?

Comment: @Barker yes, it's irrelevant too

Comment: On closer inspection, there are a few letters in the image which appear slightly faded. They spell something, but I have no idea how to use that either. This is such a tiny discovery that I'll leave it as a comment for your elaboration.

Answer (score 4):

Another partial answer that builds on previous answers by Bass and Barker and on Xenocacia's observarion. I might well be heading into the wrong direction here.

It has already been found that ...

> ... the poem consists of the names of some of the 64 hexagrams in I Ching. Xenocacia has found that some of the letters in the image are slightly lighter. These letters spell *Morse*.

Now, ...

> ... the hexagrams have numbers, but the also consist of six horizontal bars. These bars are either broken (Yin) or unbroken (Yang). The hexagrams in the poem are:
>
>    ||||¦|   13   Fellowship with men
>    ¦||¦¦|   17   Following
>    ¦¦¦¦¦¦    2   Receptive Earth
>    ||¦|¦|   37   Family / Clan
>    ¦|¦¦¦|    3   Difficulty at the beginning
>    ¦|¦¦|¦   29   Abysmal water
>    |¦¦¦|¦    4   Youthful folly
>    |¦|¦¦¦   35   Progress
>    ¦¦¦¦¦¦    2   Receptive Earth
>    |||¦|¦    6   Conflict
>    ¦|¦¦||   60   Limitation
>    ¦|||¦|   49   Revolution
>    ||¦|||    9   The Taming Power of the Small
>    |¦¦|||   26   The Taming Power of the Great
>    |¦¦|¦|   22   Grace
>    |¦||¦|   30   Clinging fire
>    ¦¦¦¦||   19   Approach
>    ¦|||||   43   Breakthrough
>    ||¦|¦|   37   Family / Clan
>
>  (The hexagrams are shown sideways here, tilted by 90° to the left.)

Unfortunately, ...

> ... I haven't found a way to get a sensible Morse message from these hexagrams. An obvious way would be to read them top-down (or left to right in the table above), where an unbroken bar is a dash and a broken bar is two dots*.
>
>  Other possible readings are to substitute an unbroken bar by just one dot or to place all hexagrams next to each other and then read line-wise. None of that has given me any useful readings, but that may be owed to the difficulty of reverse-engineering a stream of unseparated Morse signals.
>
>  I think that the numbers scribbled in the margin — 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, ... — might refer to the length of either the first words or the first Morse-encoded letters.
>
>   
>   
>  ________
>  *) When I do a web search for "hexagrams morse", one of the first results is a preview of *The Book That Proves Time Travel Happens*, which suggests just that and shows that the clinging Fire reads *tuna* and the Family decodes to *mix*.

Comment: You're really close to solve the puzzle... You may consider the possibility of "turning" hexagrams in another way... let's say clockwise... does it help you?

Comment: It probably does. `:)` (But I've gotten a rather grisly message so far.)

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all, thanks for that super interesting puzzle! I've spent the all evening trying to solve that (but didn't solve it yet).

1st step

> First of all, found ‘Morse’.

2nd step

> Tried to google text, found I-Ching, because the phrases of the strange message look similar to I-Ching names. And, the I-Ching hexagrams look similar to Morse code. For example, ䷌ looks like `-.----`.

3rd step

> But there is nothing similar in International Morse Code sheet because the length of each my code is bigger. Ok, then maybe `4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3…` means that I should join codes and then split them using given numbers as length? Anyway, the result of that doesn't make any sense for me. Then I had started to interpret ䷌ not as `-.----` but as `-..----` because there are actually two short lines between big lines. Also joined given result and tried to split it. But still nothing. Sometime later I found [this image](https://sureshemre.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/q8_iching.png) and realized that maybe I read hexagrams in wrong way. Previously I had seen [Hunter’s comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/56761/a-strange-message-in-a-library/57239#comment176074_57206) about turning hexagrams clockwise and read ䷌ as `-.----`. But after I saw the image I have an idea to read hexagrams from top to bottom as we read Excel sheets. And looks like now I have to understand how to apply given numbers, maybe it will help to convert hexagrams to Morse codes correctly.

Comment: Hey @Huner, I've little bit updated my answer. Can you take a look and just say I am on the right or wrong way.

Comment: Looking good so far. Clockwise is definitely the way to go. (It won't be too easy even after that hint.)

Comment: @artiek: as Bass suggestes, you should read them clockwise. After the resolution of the puzzle I'll post a link in which is explained the different "direction" you can use to read an hexagram (search for "dual hexagram" on google and you'll understand what I'm talking about). As already said, the last part of the puzzle is the most difficult (and the most boring, i'm afraid...)